# Creating keyboard shortcuts for context-menu options in windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

In the context-menu opened by right-clicking a file in `windows explorer` you will find the `Open with...` sub-menu giving you a list of applicatiions to open the current file with.

I was wondering if it is possible to attach a keyboard shortcut to this action.

### What I want to do

By default, my PC opens `.php` files with PhpStorm. In most of the cases this is the program I want to open PHP files with. However, in some cases, I would like to open `.php` files with Sublime Text.

I could of course right click the file and select Sublime Text from the `Open with...` menu. But I'd rather do this with a keyabord shortcut.

Is it possible to open a file with Sublime Text by let's say... Pressing the `F6` key?

Comment: Your title does not match your question?

Comment: @Moab How about this?

Comment: That will get more attention, everyone here uses this software to do what you want, but you need to know a bit of scripting to get it done.....https://www.autohotkey.com/